# Recursive in order to find commonality between sets in Python

Tags: python, recursion, set

I have multiple sets (the number is unknown) and I would like to find the commonality between the sets, if I have a match between sets (80% match) I would like to merge these 2 sets and then rerun the new set that I have against all the other sets from the beginning.

for example:

```
A : {1,2,3,4}
B : {5,6,7}
C : {1,2,3,4,5}
D : {2,3,4,5,6,7}
```

Then A runs and there is no commonality between A & B and then it runs A against C which hits the commonalty target therefore we have now a new set AC = {1,2,3,4,5} and now we compare AC to B it doesn't hit the threshold but D does therefore we have a new ACD set and now we run again and now we have a hit with B.

I'm currently using 2 loops but this solve only if I compare between 2 sets.

in order to calculate the commonality I'm using the following calculation:

```
overlap = a_set & b_set
universe = a_set | b_set
per_overlap = (len(overlap)/len(universe))
```

I think the solution should be a recursive function but I'm not so sure how to write this I'm kind of new to Python or maybe there is a different and simple way to do this.

Comment: why must it be recursive?

Comment: it doesn't - if you have a better idea that will be great

Comment: The `per_overlap` of `AC` and `D` is only 4 / 7.  It does not meet the 0.8 threshold.

Comment: Are you conscious that there could be a pitfall in your definition of the problem (triggered by 'commonality' and the `merge` operation) ? If you compare `A={1,2,3,4}`, `B={1,2,3,4,5}`, and `C={1,2,3,4,6}`, the program will not return the same result depending on the order in which you test couples (in one case `AB` and `C`, in another `AC` and `B`). Thus the problem you want to solve admits many solutions, depending on the order you iterate the couples on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this does what you are looking for.  The complexity is awful because it starts over each time it gets a match.  No recursion is needed.

```py
def commonality(s1, s2):
    overlap = s1 & s2
    universe = s1 | s2
    return (len(overlap)/len(universe))

def set_merge(s, threshold=0.8):
    used_keys = set()
    out = s.copy()
    incomplete = True
    while incomplete:
        incomplete = False
        restart = False
        for k1, s1 in list(out.items()):
            if restart:
                incomplete = True
                break
            if k1 in used_keys:
                continue
            for k2, s2 in s.items():
                if k1==k2 or k2 in used_keys:
                    continue
                print(k1, k2)
                if commonality(s1, s2) >= threshold:
                    out.setdefault(k1+k2, s1 | s2)
                    out.pop(k1)
                    if k2 in out:
                        out.pop(k2)
                    used_keys.add(k1)
                    used_keys.add(k2)
                    restart = True
                    break
    out.update({k:v for k,v in s.items() if k not in used_keys})
    return out
```

For your particular example, it only merges A and C, as any other combination is below the threshold.

```
set_dict = {
    'A' : {1,2,3,4},
    'B' : {5,6,7},
    'C' : {1,2,3,4,5},
    'D' : {2,3,4,5,6,7},
}
set_merge(set_dict)
# returns:
{'B': {5, 6, 7},
 'D': {2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7},
 'AC': {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}}
```